# Help finding a short story about aliens composed of several childlike creatures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Read a beautifully imagined story that followed 3 or 4 very different childlike beings on an ocean world. One was filmy and liked to float on the surface soaking up the waning sun. The others were...different somehow.

They hung out as a group and liked to spy on the brilliant scientists who were trying to solve the problem of acquiring energy from another star. The scientists were fond of the little creatures but shooed them away. They overheard discussion of a brilliant researcher who was going to save them all.

Every once in a while,  the little beings would go to sleep and (of course) have no memory of a big block of time.

Turns out, the scientists are the "adult" form of this species. Which is made up of the child beings grouped together.

Lots more to the story- the individual beings have a conscience, and must stop the destruction of earth, even at the cost of their own planet.

Stuck with me for 20 or so years - it was in a "best of" collection (some year) at the library. Could have been Nebula, or best of a science fiction magazine....

It haunts me! Anyone know this story?

Comment: The middle part of The Gods Themselves by Isaac Asimov. It's been asked about [numerous times already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+asimov+the+gods+themselves). Have a quick look at the search I've linked and see it it's your book.

Comment: This is likely the Asimov novel The Gods Themselves

http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1861

While some of your memories do not match, the multi-form aliens and the intradimensional power transfer do. -from deleted answer

Comment: Annawen, please let us know if the book you're asking about is *The Gods Themselves*. If so we'll link this to the other questions about the book.